How to check if a collider2d overlap with a composite collider 2d
There is a OnTriggerEnter2D function, it triggers correctly
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (!assailables.Contains(other.transform) && other.GetComponent<IAssailable>()!=null)
    {
        Debug.Log(other.transform.position);
        assailables.Add(other.transform);
    }
}

But when i try to verify it again in update function with Collider2D.overlapCollider, it will return 0.
CompositeCollider2D groundArea = GetComponent<CompositeCollider2D>();            
Debug.Log(groundArea.OverlapCollider(new ContactFilter2D(), new Collider2D[] {assailables[i].GetComponent<Collider2D>() }));

enter image description here
I don't know why it can trigger OnTriggerEnter2D but returns 0 when I call OverlapCollider, is it correct?
The compositeCollider2D is dynamic, so I want to check it again and removing from assailables when it has not been in the compositeCollider2D.

Unity by default ignores triggers (i.e. colliders with Is Trigger set to true) when performing physics queries. You need to explicitly ask it to check for triggers:
CompositeCollider2D groundArea = GetComponent<CompositeCollider2D>();            
Debug.Log(groundArea.OverlapCollider(new ContactFilter2D()
{
    useTriggers = true    // <-- notice the added line here
}, new Collider2D[] {assailables[i].GetComponent<Collider2D>() }));

See ContactFilter2D.useTriggers.
